# Copy to clipboard working after clicking twice using javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

```
function click(){
var input = document.getElementById('div');
input.focus();
document.execCommand('selectAll');
document.execCommand('copy');
}
```

The function is executed when clicking on a button:

```
<button onClick="click();">copy</button>
```

Also, I want to copy only the table inside the div element with one
 click but this copies the whole document when clicked twice.

Comment: Be aware that `.execCommand` isn't supported in Safari.

Comment: How do you attach the `click` function to a button?

Comment: To add to @evolutionxbox here is MDN's support matrix on the `execCommand` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Comment: By <button onClick="click();">copy</button>

Comment: Key wording in the MDN doc linked above: "**When** an HTML document has been switched to **designMode**, the document object **exposes** the execCommand method" - (it might be worth seeing if this needs to be triggered first)

Comment: `click` might be a bad name for a global function, since it overrides the native `window.click` method. Is `contenteditable` set for the `#div` (assuming it's a `div` element)? If not, `focus()` won't work.

Comment: No Teemu, how to add that ?

Comment: Basicly [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/dw9y48dj/), but I doubt it's not what you need. `execCommand` is purposed to be used mainly with editable elements. You could try to use [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) and [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range) objects to create a selection, which possibly could be copied to the clipboard using `document.execCommand('copy')`. I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure if it would work. Notice also, that some browser options might prevent JS to use clipboard, all users can't utilize the feature.

Comment: Aside: If you'd add an reproducable example, with the code for the button and a short div, to the post, that might prevent more down votes and the question eventually being closed. An example at http://jsfiddle.net/ would be a wellcomed bonus too.

Comment: @Mani Check out my updated post :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can't rely on users' browser will support clipboard actions, hence you might want to offer an alternative way to copy the table.

In your code, `click` as a global function's name overrides the native `window.click` method, and should not be used. This is probably the reason why you have to click the button twice (or there's something in your code which you haven't posted).

Focus can be gained only to form elements and editable elements, or elements with `tabindex` attribute. In your case `input.focus()` has no effect, hence the whole document is selected.

Here's a click handler which does what you want, though it's not very generic. It clones the first table found from `#div` and appends it to a hidden and editable `div`, where it can be selected and copied using `execCommand`s.

```
function copyTable () {
    var content = document.getElementById('div').getElementsByTagName('table')[0], // Get the element to copy
        copyPad = document.getElementById('copypad'),
        clone = content.cloneNode(true); // Clone the element to copy
    copyPad.appendChild(clone); // Add  the clone to an editable element
    copyPad.style.display = 'block'; // Some browsers refuse to select hidden content, hence show the div temporarily
    copyPad.focus(); // You can gain focus to an editable element
    try { // Not good, but tackles issues, if Security blocks the copy, or execCommand is not supported
        document.execCommand('selectAll'); // Now selects the content of the focused element only
        document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch (err) {
        // Security options of this browser blocks copy
        // or the API is not supported
        // Provide an alternative way to copy the table
    }
    copyPad.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the copyPad
    copyPad.style.display = ''; // Prevent the editable to be shown
    return;
}
```

Then we need some CSS and HTML:

```
#copypad {
    display: none;
}
```

```
<div id="div">
    <table>
       :
    </table>
</div>
<div id="copypad" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

[A working demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy7ge9rc/).

Notice also, that the content of the clipboard might vary depending on a used browser.

An alternative way would be for example to prompt user to select and copy the table, or you can read the content and show it in a textarea for copying.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :) [JSFIDDLE Link](https://jsfiddle.net/qmja8rp9/)

Html

```
<div id="divelm" contentEditable="true" style="width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid #ccc"></div>
```

Javascript

```
function SelectText(element) {
    var doc = document;
    var text = doc.getElementById(element);    
    if (doc.body.createTextRange) { // ms
        var range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(text);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        var range = doc.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(text);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

    }
}

var elm = document.getElementById('divelm');
elm.onclick = function(){

   SelectText('divelm');
   document.execCommand('copy');



}
```

Comment: " I want to copy only the table inside the div element". Also I doubt OP wants a contenteditable div.